ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken Error with domain: ':all' in Rails Session Store
I’m encountering an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error in my Rails application when using the session store configuration with domain: ':all'. The issue appears specifically when setting up the session store as follows:
`
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp_session", domain: ':all'

Configuration Files:
config/application.rb
I put the below configuration:
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true
and I have put the following configuration in application controller:
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
Rails version: 7.0
getting error as:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
app/controllers/active_admin/devise/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
...


I have cop with this problem by or CSRF protection and Turbo Streams.
In config/application.rb:
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore


edit the question with new information -- don't bury it in comments

@dubugger Please let me know if my solution to the problem is acceptable. I’ve addressed it myself.
